Restriction of multiplication of a matrix of a linear transformation
Where did this matrix in the bottom right corner come from?
And, is it a typo in the middle? I thought we needed to extend T^-1 by defining e3, not redefining e1?

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by
$$
T(\vec{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \vec{x}
$$
Then $\text{im}(T) = V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $T$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $V$. Find a $2 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that the restriction of multiplication by $A$ to $V  
 = \text{im}(T)$ equals $T^{-1}$.
Solution:
Since the two columns of the above matrix are linearly independent, we conclude that $\dim(\text{im}(T)) = 2$ and therefore $\dim(\ker(T)) = 2 - \dim(\text{im}(T)) = 2 - 2 = 0$.
By Theorem 5.7.2, it follows that $T$ is one-to-one.
Thus $T$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is the span of the columns of the given matrix. Now in particular,
$$
T(\vec{e}_1) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad T(\vec{e}_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus
$$
T^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} = \vec{e}_1, \quad T^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} = \vec{e}_2
$$
Extend $T^{-1}$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by defining
$$
T^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} = \vec{e}_1
$$
Notice that the vectors
$$
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} \right\}
$$
are linearly independent so $T^{-1}$ can be extended linearly to yield a linear transformation defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$. The matrix of $T^{-1}$, denoted as $A$, needs to satisfy
$$
A \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The vector $\vec{e}_1$ is not being redefined. It refers to the first standard basis vector $\pmatrix{1 \ 0}$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Instead, $T^{-1}\pmatrix{0\1\0}$ is being defined to be $\vec{e}_1$. The matrix in the bottom right corner is the matrix whose columns are $\vec{e}_1$, $\vec{e}_2$, $\vec{e}_1$, i.e. the result of applying $T^{-1}$ to the respective columns of the $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Answers to your questions:

The last matrix equation is just an abbreviated version of
$$
A\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right),A\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right),A\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)
$$
And these equalities are configured in the solution you refer to.

$\vec e_1$ is not redefined. Instead, $A\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$ to be $\vec e_1$. The necessity of this step is that the type of $A$ is $\mathbb R^3\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$, but the span of $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)$ is two-dimensional, so we need a vector linearly independent with them (in this case, $\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$) to form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ so that $A$ can be defined on all vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. Additionally, we can set the value of $A\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$ to any two-dimensional vector.


